# MySQL Sum-up values and insert them into table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Database:

```
Table Name: Single Database: Produkt
ID  PID     BID            ListingID    Brand   PN     Model
1   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Nike    P14    505
1   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Nike    P14    715
1   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Puma    P14    L14
1   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Puma    P14    P15
2   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Samsung XL14XL 505
2   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Samsung XL14XL 715
2   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Samsung XL14XL L14
2   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   Samsung XL14XL P14
3   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    503
3   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    503
3   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    703
3   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    713
4   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    715
4   1234    XXXXXXXX    1234-XXXXXXXX   EPSON   P14    503
```

And i want to sum up the "Model" in the lines Where "ID-Brand-PN" is the same

This is how i want my new Table to look:

```
Table Name: master Database: Produkt
ID  Brand   PN      AModel
1   Nike    P14     505, 715
1   Puma    P14     L14, P15
2   Samsung XL14XL  505, 715, L14, P14
3   EPSON   P14     503, 703, 713
4   EPSON   P14     715, 503



Pseudo-Code:
Single Row = 1

for each Single Row= NOT NULL{
IF Single Row ID and Brand and PN and Model = Exist
{
Insert into AModel Row where it exists ", Model"  
}
ELSE 
{
Write Single ID and Brand and PN and Model into Master
Single Row + 1}
```

Thanks for your time and effort, if you need more Details i´ll provide them, I don´t mind writing a php Script when i can make a trigger that which starts the Script when a new row is added to single

Comment: Can you add some code you have made and tried? (The community does not write it for ya, but helps fix what you've got)

Comment: I can, give me 1-2 Hours, i try out some code i got and if it works im gonna post it if it doesnt ill post the code with what doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the MySQL query which will generate the output table you want:

```
SELECT ID, Brand, PN, GROUP_CONCAT(Model)
FROM Single
GROUP BY ID, Brand, PN
```

Since you don't mind writing the PHP script, I'll leave that to you :-)

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eeadc2)

Comment: @finua, post it as an answer so it is clear that it is the working code, makes it better for the community :P